# LoadString() method doesn't work in C++

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, resources, string-table

I am trying to load a string from my Strin Table in the DLL file I am working on. Here is the function that is supposed to load the string into a `std::wstring` (since my project uses Unicode charset).

```
void ErrorHandler::load_error_string()
{
  m_hInst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
  wchar_t buffer[1024] = { '\0' };
  std::size_t string_length = LoadStringW(this->m_hInst, this->m_error_id, buffer, 1024);

  this->m_raw_content = std::wstring(buffer, string_length);

  CStringW output;
  output.Format(L"%d", m_raw_content.length());

  AfxMessageBox(output);
}
```

I have created the last three lines for diagnosing the method. The output of `AfxMessageBox()` is `0`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: keep in mind that `string_length` may represent the size  of a `std::wstring`, and `std::wstring` has `wchar_t`, which one can be, for instantece 2 bytes. So there is a chance that you must do a `byte conversion`... something like m_raw_content.length()*sizeof(wchar_t), of course depending on your `output.Format` implementation.

Comment: the `output` variable is just for diagnosing. I have written that because that method is not working.

Comment: Are the string resources embedded in the DLL?

Comment: yes, they are embedded in the DLL

Comment: So, Did you check the value of `string_length`? What is the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AfxGetInstanceHandle()` gives you the `HINSTANCE` of the **running executable**.  This means that your `LoadStringW` call will be looking in the exe's resource table for your string, which will fail, as the strings are in your DLL.

Instead, you'll need to grab the `HINSTANCE` of the **DLL itself** - this is provided as the first parameter to `DllMain()` in your DLL.

See this answer for an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396380/1073843

**EDIT**:
If you're using an MFC DLL, then it's possible you just need to add a call to `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());` at the top of any entry points into your DLL (before `AfxGetInstanceHandle()` is called.)

Comment: I don't have any DLLMain in my project :))

Comment: You should be able to just add one - see the post I linked to

Comment: You could try the second method given in the post I linked to - otherwise, MSDN has the details on what you have to do to override dllmain in your own dll:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148791

Comment: Or see my edit to my answer - add `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());` to your DLL entry points

Comment: AfxGetResourceHandle() ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119706/how-to-get-my-own-codes-module-handle), which will show you how to get the `HINSTANCE` of your DLL if it's an MFC DLL.